# How to get data(insights value) from google analytics account using java?

Tags: java

I used the below code...

/**

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;


//import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.AnalyticsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Accounts;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.GaData;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.GaData.ColumnHeaders;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Profiles;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Webproperties;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
//import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory;


public class HelloAnalyticsApiSample111 {

  /**
   * Be sure to specify the name of your application. If the application name is {@code null} or
   * blank, the application will log a warning. Suggested format is "MyCompany-ProductName/1.0".
   */
  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME ="Analytics API Project";

  /** Directory to store user credentials. */
  private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
      new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "store/analytics_sample");

  /**
   * Global instance of the {@link DataStoreFactory}. The best practice is to make it a single
   * globally shared instance across your application.
   */
  private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

  /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
  private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

  /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

  /**
   * Main demo. This first initializes an analytics service object. It then uses the Google
   * Analytics Management API to get the first profile ID for the authorized user. It then uses the
   * Core Reporting API to retrieve the top 25 organic search terms. Finally the results are printed
   * to the screen. If an API error occurs, it is printed here.
   *
   * @param args command line args.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    {
      int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
      int period = 86400000; // repeat every sec.

      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            System.out.println("done");
          }
        }, delay, period);
    }

    try {
      httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
      dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
      Analytics analytics = initializeAnalytics();
      String profileId = getFirstProfileId(analytics);
        System.out.println("Profile Id  :- "+profileId);
      if (profileId == null) {
        System.err.println("No profiles found.");
      } else {
        GaData gaData = executeDataQuery(analytics, profileId);
        printGaData(gaData);
      }
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
      System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
          + e.getDetails().getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
  private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    // load client secrets
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(
        JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(
            HelloAnalyticsApiSample111.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
        || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
      System.out.println(
          "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=analytics "
          + "into analytics-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
      //System.exit(1);
    }
    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
        Collections.singleton(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY)).setDataStoreFactory(
        dataStoreFactory).build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
  }

  /**
   * Performs all necessary setup steps for running requests against the API.
   *
   * @return An initialized Analytics service object.
   *
   * @throws Exception if an issue occurs with OAuth2Native authorize.
   */
  private static Analytics initializeAnalytics() throws Exception {
    // Authorization.
    Credential credential = authorize();

    // Set up and return Google Analytics API client.
    return new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
        APPLICATION_NAME).build();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the first profile id by traversing the Google Analytics Management API. This makes 3
   * queries, first to the accounts collection, then to the web properties collection, and finally
   * to the profiles collection. In each request the first ID of the first entity is retrieved and
   * used in the query for the next collection in the hierarchy.
   *
   * @param analytics the analytics service object used to access the API.
   * @return the profile ID of the user's first account, web property, and profile.
   * @throws IOException if the API encounters an error.
   */
  private static String getFirstProfileId(Analytics analytics) throws IOException {
    String profileId = null;

    // Query accounts collection.
    Accounts accounts = analytics.management().accounts().list().execute();

    if (accounts.getItems().isEmpty()) {
      System.err.println("No accounts found");
    } else {
      String firstAccountId = accounts.getItems().get(0).getId();


      // Query webproperties collection.
      Webproperties webproperties =
          analytics.management().webproperties().list(firstAccountId).execute();

      if (webproperties.getItems().isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("No Webproperties found");
      } else {
        String firstWebpropertyId = webproperties.getItems().get(0).getId();

        // Query profiles collection.
        Profiles profiles =
            analytics.management().profiles().list(firstAccountId, firstWebpropertyId).execute();

        if (profiles.getItems().isEmpty()) {
          System.err.println("No profiles found");
        } else {
          profileId = profiles.getItems().get(0).getId();
        }
      }
    }
    return profileId;
  }

  /**
   * @param analytics the analytics service object used to access the API.
   * @param profileId the profile ID from which to retrieve data.
   * @return the response from the API.
   * @throws IOException tf an API error occured.
   */
  private static GaData executeDataQuery(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
    return analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + "46509804", // Table Id. ga: + profile id.
        "yesterday", // Start date.
        "yesterday", // End date.
        "ga:pageviews, ga:sessions, ga:uniquePageviews") // Metrics.
        .setDimensions("")
        .setSort("-ga:sessions")
        .setFilters("ga:medium==organic")
        .setMaxResults(20)
        .execute();
  }



  /**
   * Prints the output from the Core Reporting API. The profile name is printed along with each
   * column name and all the data in the rows.
   *
   * @param results data returned from the Core Reporting API.
   */



private static void printGaData(GaData results) {

     //csv printer
     PrintWriter pw = null;
     try {
         pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.csv")));
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("I could not open the output csv file, see stacktrace below:");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

  // If pw is still null here, the PrintWriter is not available and continuing would be pointless
     if (pw==null) {
         return;
     }

   //getting the queries to print
     if (results.getRows() == null || results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
         // Although technically not ''wrong'', using printf here is not the best solution
         pw.println("No results Found.");
         // But it might be better to just write that message in the output window, and not in the csv file
         System.out.println("No results Found.");
     } else {

    // Print column headers.
       for (ColumnHeaders header : results.getColumnHeaders()) {
           pw.print(header.getName() + ", ");
       }
       pw.println();

      // Print actual data.
      for (List<String> row : results.getRows()) {
        for (String column : row) {
          pw.print(column + ",");
        }
        pw.println();
      } 
      pw.close();
    }
  }
}
```

**/

but still given error as below....

> Sep 11, 2014 10:27:17 AM
>   com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory
>   setPermissionsToOwnerOnly WARNING: unable to change permissions for
>   everybody: C:\Documents and Settings\sk4\store\analytics_sample Enter
>   Client ID and Secret from
>   https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=analytics into
>   analytics-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json
>   2014-09-11 10:27:17.359:INFO::Logging to STDERR via
>   org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog 2014-09-11 10:27:17.375:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
>   Please open the following address in your browser: 2014-09-11
>   10:27:17.406:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:1699
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=1097630614596-b6n284d2k6spglkfgag9dqki4jq0bld4.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1699/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly
>   Attempting to open that address in the default browser now... done

Please if some one know how to resolved these error...
or having another code which run properly please send me...

Comment: You've got entirely too much code to sift through.  First, start with looking up the message you're getting.  Second, you're not getting an error (from what I see); it's a warning.  Those are different things.